# Validation? Yes or No, otherwise Error. SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to add to current query where a certain field name must contain either '**Y**' or '**N**'. I'm currently using substrings and isnumeric functions to manipulate the data within.

Here is an example:

```
(
      LEN(STERLING_RETURN_SIGNAL) > 1 
      or ISNUMERIC(substring(STERLING_RETURN_SIGNAL,1,1)) = 1
)
```

So the `STERLING_RETURN_SIGNAL`, must either be '**Y**' or '**N**' otherwise +('Error message').

Many thanks. Using Sql Server Management Studio.

Please note, I am a beginner...

Comment: Why would you think that `ISNUMERIC` is part of the solution (it rarely, if ever, actually is) when what you're looking for isn't numeric?

Comment: Should have explained that I am looking for errors in my code, that's another purpose of my query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    case
       when 
          STERLING_RETURN_SIGNAL in ('Y','y','N','n') 
          then STERLING_RETURN_SIGNAL
       else 
          'Invalid value for signal' 
    end as signal
from ...
```

Comment: SQL server is (by default) case insensitive, so `('Y','N')` would be sufficient in most cases.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I'm having trouble trying to implement this into existing code.

Comment: @SamuelMaile What does the existing code look like? Could you update your question with more information please.

Comment: The interesting thing about the query you posted is that it is showing all items in configuration where the tax year is 2005 and sterling return signal is multiple chars or it is numeric... like it is finding all the items with invalid sterling return signals.

Comment: Yes, it is finding all the items which are invalid.. I should have noted I am doing a bit of error reporting. It's picking out all numeric, if true it will flag up to be investigated. 

But I want to ensure that only Y or N can be inputted. Else Error message?

Comment: @SamuelMaile so just list out the fields you want in the select and add the case statement in that list. e.g. select a, b, case when ... end as signal from ...

Comment: @AdrianWragg: That depends on the collation used, which I don't think we should make any assumptions on. Rather, I'd recommend using the UPPER function on the column, then compare the results to capitalized 'Y' & 'N' values.

Comment: @Kahn Yup, I agree. I used "default" and "most cases" deliberately.